# Failed to commit edit, error: googleapi: Error 403: Target SDK of artifact is too low: 39., forbidden

Tags: react-native, google-api, bitrise

I've been searching the exact question maybe already raised but none found.

All bitrise steps are success except for this one in `Google Play Deploy Step`

> Failed to commit edit, error: googleapi: Error 403: Target SDK of artifact is too low: 39., forbidden

I spent hours on this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably not targeting the now required api level of 33. https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk